# Group pairwise categories together

Tags: r, matrix, tapply

I am currently working with a dataset where loans are displayed with a purpose for the loan and an associated loan grade for each loan.

The dataset is called **loancase** and one of the columns is the *purpose* while another column is *grade*.
[image]

Below I have the matrix which is to be filled in a pairwise manner with proportions. Each row should total to 100 percent meaning each entry is the proportion for that specific purpose that received that grade. For instance, the row for *[Car, ]* may look like 20, 20, 0, 0, 20, 0, 40.

Note that the current data placeholder is NA and I am trying to replace that with a vector listing each desired entry.

```
matrix(data = NA, nrow = 14, ncol = 7, dimnames = list(levels(loancase$purpose), levels(loancase$grade)))
```

[image]

How do I achieve this goal of filling in each entry with the desired value? I am currently thinking I use tapply() but don't know how to achieve that. Here is the current code that will go in the place of "NA" but it is not correct as of now.

```
grades.per.purpose = tapply(loancase$grade, levels(loancase$purpose), sum)
```

Comment: Please provide data as plain text, not images, so users can copy/paste.

Comment: Added relevant lines of code

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't supply usable data, I'll make up a toy example:

```
df = read.table(text = "grade   purpose   amount
            A  Car   100
            B  Car   200
            C  Car   100
            A  Moving  200
            B  Moving  50
            B  Moving  50", header = TRUE)
```

We want to show `Car` loans are 50% B-Grade, 25% A- and C-grade.  And `Moving` loans are 67% A-grade, 33% B-grade.

I like to use `dplyr` library for this kind of grouping and summarising:

```
library(dplyr)
x = df %>% 
    group_by(purpose) %>% 
    mutate(purpose.total = sum(amount)) %>% 
    group_by(purpose, grade) %>% 
    summarise(percent = sum(amount / purpose.total))
```

The result:

```
  purpose  grade   percent
1     Car      A 0.2500000
2     Car      B 0.5000000
3     Car      C 0.2500000
4  Moving      A 0.6666667
5  Moving      B 0.3333333
```

To group it into a square like you asked for, try the `tidyr` library:

```
tidyr::spread(x, key = grade, value = percent, fill = 0)
```

Result:

```
  purpose         A         B     C
1     Car 0.2500000 0.5000000  0.25
2  Moving 0.6666667 0.3333333  0.00
```

Comment: This is the exact type of result I'm trying to achieve thank you. Unfortunately for these purposes I cannot use any external libraries. Is there a way to do this using native R functions?

Comment: @user1713336 R is much easier to use if you're allowed external libraries.  Are you sure you can't get packages?

Comment: I would love to use libraries as well but I am restricted from using them for  this project.

Comment: @user1713336 All I can think of is `aggregate` for summarising the data...  I'm not sure of a clean way to spread the data out.  Please edit your question so that (1) it includes actual, usable data which somebody could copy-paste, and (2) clarify that you're not allowed to use packages.

Comment: To have the percentages (proportions, actually), you can do with `base R` only the following: `with(df, ave(amount,  purpose, FUN = function(x) x/sum(x)))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas That doesn't quite summarise by grade.  It says `Moving` loans are 67% A, 17% B and 17% B again (instead of 67% A, 33% B)

Comment: @lebelinoz OK, I will post an answer.

Comment: @lebelinoz - `reshape` with `direction="wide"` is the equivalent of `spread`

Answer (score 1):

Though I believe that it's nonsense to be forbidden to use packages, there is a `base R` solution, with the final result presented in a way that might please the OP.

```
xt <- xtabs(amount ~ grade + purpose, df)
t(xt)/colSums(xt)
```